# How to record the name of the file/line that called the current function in PHP?

Tags: php, logging, error-logging

I am writing a lightweight logging class in php.
How do I automatically record the filename/function/line number where the function in the Log class is being called from and save the line number and time and stuff without making my users bother with entering  `$__LINE__` and `$__FILE__`  every time they call the function. Is there something that I can implicitly call.

Example:

```
class Log {
static private $instance;
static $logfile;
private function __construct(){
    // doesn't need to do anything
    // one logging object to avoid/control future/potential race conditions
}
public function getInstance(){
    if(!Self::$instance) {
        Self::$instance = new Log();
    } else {
        return Self::$instance;
    }
}

public function criticalLog($string){
    // I want this to be logging line number, filename

}
}
```

Now I want to be able to something like in say file api.php line number 15

```
logInstance.criticalLog("This log is important");
```

In my log file, I'd like to see

`12/10/09-11:15 api.php 15  This log is important`

Any ideas? I had a look at PEAR and log4php solutions, but they seem pretty heavy for what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function, it would appear it provides all the information you need:

```
function, line, file, class, object, type, args
```

Comment: Seconded, debug_backtrace() is the way to go. In my experience, though, it is very expensive, and in production use, I tend to turn it off. But this applies to all logging solutions that probably all rely on debug_backtrace().

Comment: Yup, I usually use it for debugging and switch it off when the system goes live.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried it yet but makes sense from the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Magic constants  : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Won't help here, as they will return the criticalLog() function's file and line. He would have to include the constants as parameters to the call, which is doable but cumbersome.